# Adding document to firestore when Stripe subscription created

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am passing the clientreferenceid when i go to the payment link
And i want to save the clientrefernceid as a document in firestore if the subscription was created
i will just send you my code... of course you dont have to help me but i would be sooo grateful!!! have been struggling with this for a very long time!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().keys.webhooks);
const endpointSecret = functions.config().keys.signing;

exports.subscribeStart = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,
    response) => {
  // Get the signature from the request header
  const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

  try {
    const subscriptionData = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody,
        sig, endpointSecret);

    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    try {
      admin.initializeApp();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("no problem", err);
    }

    const firestore = admin.firestore();
    const subscriberCollection = firestore.collection("Subscribers");

    const docRef = await subscriberCollection.add(subscriptionData);

    return response.json({received: true, ref: docRef.id});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error handling event:", err);
    return response.status(400).send(Webhook Error: ${err.message});
  }
});
```

This code does create a firestore document with the raw body data. Actually i dont need the raw body data but just the client reference id i passed through the url... Do you have any idea how to do this?

Tried:
adding document when stripe subscription is created that includes data which i passed when opening the link (tried it via url parameter client_reference_id)

Expected: client_reference_id to show up in firestore as document

Comment: I don't think it's mentioned anywhere, but what event are you listening for / receiving ? If you're looking for the `client_reference_id`, then it would have to be `checkout.session.completed`, and you'd get the attribute in `['data']['object']['client_reference_id']`

Comment: I am listening to a subscription started event. The client reference id is also showing up in the response body of the log in stripe but not in  firestore for some reason. acutally the client reference id would be the only field i would need to store in firestore. do you know how i need to change the code so i can archive this?? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: yeah, listen to `checkout.session.completed`. It gives you the Checkout Session object, which includes the `client_reference_id`. I'm guessing you're listening to `customer.subscription.created`, which gives you the Subscription object, which doesn't have a `client_reference_id`. Also, you say you're getting the `client_reference_id` in the Response, I'm assuming that's the response related to the Checkout Session object.